# Kerberos Authentication Issue in WSO2 Identity server 5.9.0

Tags: wso2, kerberos, windows-authentication, ids, wso2-identity-server

We have configured IWA kerberos in WSO2 Identity server 5.9.0 on Kubernetes platform,as per the official documentation of WSO2.

While we are testing we are receiving  500 Internal server error.

Here are the logs:

> ERROR
>   {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].[bridgeservlet]}
>   - Servlet.service() for servlet [bridgeservlet] in context with path [/] threw exception [Cannot handle IWA authentication request from the
>   same host as the KDC] with root cause javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   Cannot handle IWA authentication request from the same host as the
>   KDC.

Comment: Hi @Rishabh can you explain your setup a bit more in detail? Especially how KDC(ie. the AD), client machine and IS are configured.

Comment: We have followed the 5.9.0 version of wso2 document.
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-iwa-on-linux/

In 5.7.0 its working fine, but when we are testing the same on 5.9.0, it's giving 500 Internal server error

Comment: Are you testing it from within the cluster?

Comment: Yes we are testing within the same cluster.
In Kubernetes, we have setup like Nginx as LB and Nginx is pointed to Master IP.

Answer (score 0):

not an exact solution to your issue, but have you tried setting up the ldap users store? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhkwN8tr41k

I am also using/testing WSO2 IS within K8S and the guy in the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gR6ky3QHr1s) was able to manage connecting wso2 is with SSO.

I am currently at the point where I was able to connect to the AD, and can see the users and groups, and trying to figure out how to do the SSO :)

Nevertheless what has helped me with this task was the wireshark and ldap browser. Perhaps wireshark can help you also with your 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to a bug in the tomcat version used by the Identity Server 5.9.0. In the IWA Kerberos authenticator, there is a [validation](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-local-auth-iwa-kerberos/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.iwa/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authenticator/iwa/servlet/IWAServlet.java#L65) carried out to prevent the client and Identity server from running on the same host but due to a [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63570) in the tomcat version(9.0.22) used, the req.getLocalAddr() returns the remote address, therefore, this check always returns true causing this error. Git issue - https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/8028